# KMyMoney isn't up to date in elementaryOS AppCenter

Tags: applications, appcenter, release-hera

The AppCenter offers at the moment version 5.0.1 of KMyMoney. According to https://kmymoney.org/ the latest version is 5.0.7. My bank rejected the online access via KMyMoney 5.0.1.

Can I find somewhere a time schedule or something like that when AppCenter will be updated to the latest release of a specific software?

Answer (score 1):

latest version thats in tied to ubunthu repo can be found here:
https://pkgs.org/download/kmymoney

that is a debian packaged version

> kmymoney_5.0.6-1_amd64.deb

other wise if you want the latest version you can download source files and build it

https://kmymoney.org/

there are instruction in the "README.cmake" file

Comment: never heard before from "pkgs.org" and never build something from source myself but I will have a look at it, thanks for the hint.